# How to remove hover effect from <md-button>?

Tags: angularjs

when I move mouse over **md-button** it highlights and when I click it remains highlighted but I don't want that I want **remove hover effect**  how can I do this?

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: `<md-button data-ng-click="viewPdfReportOfTask(task.id,task.taskName,$event)" aria-label="REPORT" > <img src="assets/images/pdf.png"  style="height:40px;"> </md-button>`

Comment: I got solution just add **style attribute** in md-button as `<md-button data-ng-click="viewPdfReportOfTask(task.id,task.taskName,$event)" aria-label="REPORT" style="background:transparent"> <img src="assets/images/pdf.png" style="height:40px;"> </md-button>`

Answer (score -1):

You can try `md-no-ink` attribute for `md-button`

More: https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.9/demo/button